# Calculating first day Date of a week from a given week number

Tags: php, days, date-arithmetic

I have a question and can't find that specific answer.
In my application, my work year start on july 1 every years. So 52 weeks later, I start again on july first. What I want is a field that I enter let say week 32. I want to have the answer of what is the first day of that specified week and show it as date format. So in other words, if I put week 1 in the field, it will give me the result = July 1 and if I put Week 2 in the field, it will gives me july 8, etc. But I think that every year could change. So I need a calculation that will do this. Is it possible in php?
Tks for help
Seby

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm using  php

Comment: No problem, I already thought so.

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime("July 1 2013 +".$monthNum." months");
```

something like this?

Comment: Could you give a more detail explanation in action?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  The doc for the function is available @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php If you have any specific questions please ask